# Add the key value based on property in array object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to map the key value pair based on property in javascript.
I need to add the title property to obj1 if the name matches.

```
var obj1 = [
  {"item": 1, code: "SG", name: "Engg", status: "A"},
  {"item": 2, code: "TH", name: "Civil", status: "C"},
  {"item": 1, code: "ML", name: "IT", status: "I"}
] 

var obj2 = [
   {"name": "Engg", "title": "Service"},
   {"name": "Civil", "title": "MRT"}
 ]
```

Expected Output

```
var newobj= [
  {"item": 1, code: "SG", name: "Engg", status: "A", title: "Service"},
  {"item": 2, code: "TH", name: "Civil", status: "C",title:"MRT"},
  {"item": 1, code: "ML", name: "IT", status: "I"}

]
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
var obj1 = [{
    "item": 1,
    code: "SG",
    name: "Engg",
    status: "A"
  },
  {
    "item": 2,
    code: "TH",
    name: "Civil",
    status: "C"
  },
  {
    "item": 1,
    code: "ML",
    name: "IT",
    status: "I"
  }
]

var obj2 = [{
    "name": "Engg",
    "title": "Service"
  },
  {
    "name": "Civil",
    "title": "MRT"
  }
]

const a = obj1.map(el => ({
  ...el,
  ...obj2.find(item => item.name === el.name)
}))

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Build titles object from obj2

2) Use `reduce` method on obj1 and update title from obj2.

```js
var obj1 = [
  { item: 1, code: "SG", name: "Engg", status: "A" },
  { item: 2, code: "TH", name: "Civil", status: "C" },
  { item: 1, code: "ML", name: "IT", status: "I" }
];

var obj2 = [
  { name: "Engg", title: "Service" },
  { name: "Civil", title: "MRT" }
];

const titles = obj2.reduce((acc, { name, title }) => (acc[name] = title, acc), {});

const updated = obj1.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  title: titles[item.name] || ""
}));

console.log(updated);
```